# Help understand GLSL directional light on iOS (left handed coord system)

Tags: shaders, glsl, lighting, gpu

I now have changed from GLKBaseEffect to a own shader implementation. I have a shader management, which compiles and applies a shader to the right time and does some shader setup like lights. Please have a look at my vertex shader code. Now, light direction should be provided in eye space, but I think there is something I don't get right.

After I setup my view with camera I save a lightMatrix to transform the light from global space to eye space.

My modelview and projection setup:

```
- (void)setupViewWithWidth:(int)width height:(int)height camera:(N3DCamera *)aCamera {

    aCamera.aspect = (float)width / (float)height;
    float aspect = aCamera.aspect;
    float far = aCamera.far;
    float near = aCamera.near;
    float vFOV = aCamera.fieldOfView;

    float top = near * tanf(M_PI * vFOV / 360.0f);
    float bottom = -top;
    float right = aspect * top;
    float left = -right;

    // projection
    GLKMatrixStackLoadMatrix4(projectionStack, GLKMatrix4MakeFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far));

    // identity modelview
    GLKMatrixStackLoadMatrix4(modelviewStack, GLKMatrix4Identity);

    // switch to left handed coord system (forward = z+)
    GLKMatrixStackMultiplyMatrix4(modelviewStack, GLKMatrix4MakeScale(1, 1, -1));  

    // transform camera
    GLKMatrixStackMultiplyMatrix4(modelviewStack, GLKMatrix4MakeWithMatrix3(GLKMatrix3Transpose(aCamera.orientation)));
    GLKMatrixStackTranslate(modelviewStack, -aCamera.position.x, -aCamera.position.y, -aCamera.position.z);
}

- (GLKMatrix4)modelviewMatrix {
    return GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(modelviewStack);
}

- (GLKMatrix4)projectionMatrix {
    return GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(projectionStack);
}

- (GLKMatrix4)modelviewProjectionMatrix {
    return GLKMatrix4Multiply([self projectionMatrix], [self modelviewMatrix]);
}

- (GLKMatrix3)normalMatrix {
    return GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3([self modelviewProjectionMatrix]), NULL);
}
```

After that, I save the lightMatrix like this:

```
[self.renderer setupViewWithWidth:view.drawableWidth height:view.drawableHeight camera:self.camera];
self.lightMatrix = [self.renderer modelviewProjectionMatrix];
```

And just before I render a 3d entity of the scene graph, I setup the light config for its shader with the lightMatrix like this:

```
- (N3DLight)transformedLight:(N3DLight)light transformation:(GLKMatrix4)matrix {
    N3DLight transformedLight = N3DLightMakeDisabled();
    if (N3DLightIsDirectional(light)) {
        GLKVector3 direction = GLKVector3MakeWithArray(GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(matrix, light.position).v);
        direction = GLKVector3Negate(direction);    // HACK -> TODO: get lightMatrix right!
        transformedLight = N3DLightMakeDirectional(direction, light.diffuse, light.specular);
    } else {
        ...
    } 
    return transformedLight;
}
```

You see the line, where I **negate** the direction!? I can't explain why I need to do that, but if I do, the lights are correct as far as I can tell.

**Please help me, to get rid of the hack.**

I'am scared that this has something to do, with my switch to left handed coord system.

My vertex shader looks like this:

```
attribute highp     vec4    inPosition;
attribute lowp      vec4    inNormal;
...

uniform highp   mat4    MVP;
uniform highp   mat4    MV;
uniform lowp    mat3    N;

uniform lowp    vec4    constantColor;
uniform lowp    vec4    ambient;
uniform lowp    vec4    light0Position;
uniform lowp    vec4    light0Diffuse;
uniform lowp    vec4    light0Specular;

varying lowp    vec4    vColor;
varying lowp    vec3    vTexCoord0;

vec4 calcDirectional(vec3 dir, vec4 diffuse, vec4 specular, vec3 normal) {
    float NdotL = max(dot(normal, dir), 0.0);
    return NdotL * diffuse;
}

...    

vec4 calcLight(vec4 pos, vec4 diffuse, vec4 specular, vec3 normal) {
    if (pos.w == 0.0) {             // Directional Light
        return calcDirectional(normalize(pos.xyz), diffuse, specular, normal);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

void main(void) {

    // position
    highp vec4 position = MVP * inPosition;        
    gl_Position = position;

    // normal
    lowp vec3 normal = inNormal.xyz / inNormal.w;
    normal = N * normal;
    normal = normalize(normal);

    // colors
    vColor = constantColor * ambient;

    // add lights
    vColor += calcLight(light0Position, light0Diffuse, light0Specular, normal);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Out of the box, OpenGL is a right handed coordinate system...

Comment: @stephelton: [No, it isn't.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/17519/why-does-directx-use-a-left-handed-coordinate-system/88776#88776)

Comment: @NicolBolas umm, yes it is...

Comment: @stephelton: Regurgitating wrong information doesn't make it right. Clip-space, NDC space, Window-Space, using the *default* values of OpenGL is *left handed*. All of the "right-handed" spaces you're used to, like view space, model space, and so forth? Those don't exist in OpenGL ES 2.0+. They don't exist in core Desktop GL 3.2+. If you're using shaders, your final values are in a left-handed coordinate system. Your projection matrix can take right-handed values, but it needs to negate the Z, just as the fixed-function OpenGL projection matrix does.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I didn't recognize your link in your first response until now. That's very interesting, I'm glad you pointed it out, and I'm glad that I read it. There seems to be a great deal of confusion related to handedness and OpenGL; just search something along the lines of "is OpenGL right or left handed?" You should get on chat more often :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself. My engine represents the light direction, as the direction from the light source to the target surface. **BUT**, the shader needs the direction towards the light source and hence I have to negate the direction vector before passing to the shader.